# how to convert time and time zone into date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

One column of CSV file includes time and time zone. 
Here is one value under the column: `2018-05-20 15:05:51.065 America/New_York`. I wonder, how can I convert the value to the `2019-05-20` format? There are over a half-million rows in the CSV file.

Comment: You may take advantage of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321466/how-to-convert-string-timezones-in-form-country-city-into-datetime-tzinfo further with  `datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 0):

Split your column into date, time and zone using string manipulators, regex etc . Have a standard time zone to follow (eg: UTC)

Now

1. Get time difference between the zone and UTC using below,

[How to convert string timezones in form (Country/city) into datetime.tzinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321466/how-to-convert-string-timezones-in-form-country-city-into-datetime-tzinfo)

2. Use this difference to the time you have split already and then change date based on 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to be a string, just strip away everything past the first space: 
`"2018-05-20 15:05:51.065 America/New_York".split(' ')[0]`

EDIT:
If you want it to be a timezone-aware datetime object, you can do it easily with pytz package:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone


string_date = "2018-05-20 15:05:51.065 America/New_York"
tz = timezone(string_date.split(' ')[len(string_date.split(' '))-1])

unaware = " ".join(string_date.split(' ')[:len(string_date.split(' '))-1])
unaware_datetime = datetime.strptime(unaware, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

aware_datetime = unaware_datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz)
```